# How to link static page in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a method in controller as `def match` which is in `JobsController`.

```
def match
end
```

I have created match.html.erb in /views/jobs/match.html.erb, I want this code output to come as it is a static page.
I have given a link in index page to render this match.html.erb file like this:

```
<td><%= link_to 'Match', jobs_match_path %></td>
```

I have defined match path in route file like this:

```
  get 'jobs/match', :to => redirect('jobs/match.html')
```

But I am getting an error as:

> ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in JobsController#show Couldn't find Job
>   with 'id'=match

Comment: if i put before resources, i am getting  error " page isn’t redirecting properly"  in browser

Comment: @vinutha Run `rails routes` in your console , and check what is actual route for match method.

Answer (score 1):

As the others said. But I'd do this way

```
resources :jobs do
  get 'match', to: 'jobs#match', on: :collection
end
```

So your routes definitions are order-independent